# How do I update array of object is in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

My model is:-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const supplierProduct = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //convert id to normal form
    supplier_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //convert id to normal form
    category_details: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      category_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      sub_category_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      Purchase_Price: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("supplierProduct", supplierProduct);
```

my router is:-

```
router.post("/supplierProduct-save", async (req, res) => {
  try {
   
    const supplier_id = req.body.supplier_id;
    const category_details = req.body.category_details;
   

  
  

    const supplierProduct_data = new supplierProduct({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      supplier_id: supplier_id,
      category_details: category_details,
    });

  
   

    const savedSupplierProduct = await datapart.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedSupplierProduct);
   
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

I am getting output :

_id
636c86f1b68dc2d9facc571a
supplier_id
"636b3b6e415791c393904d91"

category_details
Array

0
Object
category_name
"rice"
sub_category_name
"a3"
Purchase_Price
"1000"
createdAt
2022-11-10T05:06:57.586+00:00
updatedAt
2022-11-10T05:06:57.586+00:00
__v
0

_id
636c86f1b68dc2d9facc571a
supplier_id
"636b3b6e415791c393904d91"

category_details
Array

0
Object
category_name
"rice"
sub_category_name
"a3"
Purchase_Price
"1000"
createdAt
2022-11-10T05:06:57.586+00:00

here I have to add more category details using the supplier id how we can achive this tings please help..

Comment: Do you need to add the category details in the existing `/supplierProduct-save` end-point or create a new one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your category details its not a array
if u wanna add more category Detail convert to this

```
category_details: [
     {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      category_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      sub_category_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      Purchase_Price: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
     }
   ],
```